# SQL Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

I am working on an Enterprise Database Management course project and cannot seem to get my error handling to perform correctly on a transaction.  My instructor advised me to take a look at the error "Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure pInsertVolunteer, Line 28
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. " but I have not yet found any solutions that are working for this transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pInsertVolunteer]
    @LastName varchar(255),
    @FirstName varchar(255),
    @DateOfBirth date,
    @Note varchar(MAX),
    @ModifiedBy nvarchar(50),
    @Success bit Output,
    @ErrorStatus Nvarchar(50) Output

 AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
        @TempVolunteerID int,
        @VolunteerID int,
        @VolunteerPersonID int;

    SET @TempVolunteerID = 0;
    SET @Success = 0;
    SET @ErrorStatus = '';

END
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @TempVolunteerID = VolunteerID
    FROM Volunteer.VolunteerInfo
        WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName AND DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth
        If @TempVolunteerID <>0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @ErrorStatus = 'Person Already Exists';
                SET @Success = 0;
                RAISERROR (@ErrorStatus, 16,1);
            END
        IF @@ERROR <>0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @ErrorStatus = CONVERT (nvarchar(50),@@ERROR) + '-1000';
                SET @Success = 0;
                RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 16,1);
            END
    
    INSERT INTO Volunteer.VolunteerInfo (LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth)
    values (@LastName, @FirstName, @DateofBirth)
            SET @Success = 1;
            SET @ErrorStatus = 0;

    SELECT @VolunteerPersonID = VolunteerID
    FROM Volunteer.VolunteerInfo
    If @VolunteerPersonID = 0 OR @VolunteerPersonID IS NULL
            BEGIN
                    SET @Success =0;
                    SET @ErrorStatus = '8008: PersonID must be valid';
                        
                    RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus,16,1);
            END

    Insert into Volunteer.VolunteerNotes (Note,ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy)
    Values (@Note,SYSDATETIME(), @ModifiedBy)

            SET @VolunteerPersonID = @@IDENTITY;
            SET @Success = 1;
            SET @ErrorStatus = 0;
            SET NOCOUNT OFF;
        
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @ErrorStatus = @ErrorStatus + CONVERT (nvarchar(50), @@ERROR);
                END
                    SET @Success = 0;
                    SET @ErrorStatus = @ErrorStatus + '-1001';
                    RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 15,1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            
        END CATCH       
GO
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Formatting your code and using indentation carefully will help others immensely understand it. But you don't seem to understand try/catch. You have `IF @@ERROR <>0` after the first SELECT statement. That is logical nonsense and will never be reached. Any exception will be caught in a catch block (if it exists). No idea why you need to catch errors only to re-raise them and set an output parameter - but maybe you have very atypical requirements. Generally you shouldn't be trying to undermine the exception logic by using your own.

Comment: You should really be using `THROW` too, as the documentation on `RAISERROR` tells you.

Comment: And it seems you try to "manually" enforce a natural key (name, dob). Don't - that should be enforced with a unique constraint. In addition, you should be using THROW rather than RAISERROR.  Lastly - read the doc about  [XACT_ABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Searching about @@IDENTITY and why that might be a bad idea as well.

Comment: Lastly, Erland has a good discussion of [error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) - it is not a straight-forward as one might think. Bookmark his site as it is full of useful information.

Comment: Are you executing the proc directly from an SSMS query window or some other method?  You will get that error if a transaction is open before the proc call an the proc rolls back the transaction after an error.

Comment: I don't see any way you can get that error if the sproc is run by itself with no outer transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much @SMor, I'll check out those resources.  I was using syntax from our class lectures, which is most likely why a lot of this looked wonky/outdated.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I was executing from the object explorer panel, if that makes sense.  I was getting the error Msg 50000, Level 15, State 1.  My instructor advised me to research the error included in my original post to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pInsertVolunteer] @LastName    VARCHAR(255), 
                                          @FirstName   VARCHAR(255), 
                                          @DateOfBirth DATE, 
                                          @Note        VARCHAR(MAX), 
                                          @ModifiedBy  NVARCHAR(50), 
                                          @Success     BIT OUTPUT, 
                                          @ErrorStatus NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
-- settings
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
-- variables
DECLARE @TempVolunteerID INT = 0, @VolunteerID INT, @VolunteerPersonID INT;
SET @Success = 0;
SET @ErrorStatus = '';

-- controled transaction
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;
   SELECT @TempVolunteerID = VolunteerID
   FROM Volunteer.VolunteerInfo
   WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
         AND LastName = @LastName
         AND DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth;
   IF @TempVolunteerID <> 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @ErrorStatus = 'Person Already Exists';
      SET @Success = 0;
      RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 16, 1);
   END;
   IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @ErrorStatus = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @@ERROR) + '-1000';
      SET @Success = 0;
      RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 16, 1);
   END;
   INSERT INTO Volunteer.VolunteerInfo
      (LastName, 
       FirstName, 
       DateOfBirth
      )
   VALUES
      (@LastName, 
       @FirstName, 
       @DateofBirth
      );
   SET @Success = 1;
   SET @ErrorStatus = 0;
   SELECT @VolunteerPersonID = VolunteerID
   FROM Volunteer.VolunteerInfo;
   IF @VolunteerPersonID = 0
      OR @VolunteerPersonID IS NULL
   BEGIN
      SET @Success = 0;
      SET @ErrorStatus = '8008: PersonID must be valid';
      RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 16, 1);
   END;
   INSERT INTO Volunteer.VolunteerNotes
      (Note, 
       ModifiedDate, 
       ModifiedBy
      )
   VALUES
      (@Note, 
       SYSDATETIME(), 
       @ModifiedBy
      );
   SET @VolunteerPersonID = @@IDENTITY;
   SET @Success = 1;
   SET @ErrorStatus = 0;
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      SELECT @ErrorStatus = @ErrorStatus + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), ERROR_MESSAGE());
   END;
   SET @Success = 0;
   SET @ErrorStatus = @ErrorStatus + '-1001';
   RAISERROR(@ErrorStatus, 15, 1);
END CATCH;       
GO
```